# How does this advert Count down method from apk via jadx work?

Tags: android, apk, smali

How does this advert Count down method from apk via jadx work?

I decompiled an apk using jadx and found the following method after many hours of head scratching and debugging. Looks like this is written to confuse people like me!

The countdown lasts for 5 seconds. and then allows the user to skip the advert.

Here is the code:

```
/* 69 */        public static String a(long j, int i) {
                    String str;
                    long j2;
                    String str2;
                    String str3;
/* 70 */            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
/* 70 */            if (j < 0) {
/* 70 */                str = "-";
                    } else {
/* 96 */                str = "";
                    }
/* 71 */            sb.append(str);
/* 72 */            long abs = Math.abs(j);
/* 73 */            long j3 = abs / 60;
/* 74 */            long j4 = j3 / 60;
/* 74 */            if (j4 > 0) {
/* 77 */                i = Math.max(i, 5);
/* 76 */                j2 = j3 % 60;
                    } else {
/* 96 */                j2 = j3;
                    }
/* 79 */            String l = Long.toString(abs % 60);
/* 80 */            if (l.length() == 1) {
/* 81 */                String valueOf = String.valueOf(l);
/* 81 */                str2 = valueOf.length() == 0 ? new String("0") : "0".concat(valueOf);
                    } else {
/* 96 */                str2 = l;
                    }
/* 82 */            String l2 = Long.toString(j2);
/* 83 */            if (l2.length() != 1) {
/* 92 */                str3 = l2;
                    } else if (i > 3) {
/* 84 */                String valueOf2 = String.valueOf(l2);
/* 84 */                str3 = valueOf2.length() == 0 ? new String("0") : "0".concat(valueOf2);
                    } else {
/* 92 */                str3 = l2;
                    }
/* 84 */            if (i > 4) {
/* 87 */                sb.append(j4);
/* 87 */                sb.append(":");
/* 87 */                sb.append(str3);
/* 87 */                sb.append(":");
/* 87 */                sb.append(str2);
/* 88 */                return ((xv) a.get()).a(sb.toString());
                    }
/* 90 */            sb.append(str3);
/* 90 */            sb.append(":");
/* 90 */            sb.append(str2);
/* 91 */            return ((xv) a.get()).a(sb.toString());
                }
```

LogCat Results from first run:

v2 is the returned value, v3 is always the same!

```
23175:12-05  08:59:00.221 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 0     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:00 v2: 0:00
25854:12-05  08:59:01.277 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 1     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:01 v2: 0:01
25879:12-05  08:59:01.278 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 15    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:15 v2: 0:15
27599:12-05  08:59:01.446 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 14    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:14 v2: 0:14
29937:12-05  08:59:02.167 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 2     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:02 v2: 0:02
30011:12-05  08:59:02.169 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 15    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:15 v2: 0:15
43979:12-05  08:59:07.175 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 7     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:07 v2: 0:07
67367:12-05  08:59:10.846 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 8     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:08 v2: 0:08
67393:12-05  08:59:10.846 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 15    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:15 v2: 0:15
70777:12-05  08:59:10.947 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 0     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:00 v2: 0:00
70841:12-05  08:59:10.948 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
85460:12-05  08:59:11.465 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 0     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:00 v2: 0:00
85562:12-05  08:59:11.469 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
90592:12-05  08:59:11.625 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 0     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:00 v2: 0:00
90675:12-05  08:59:11.627 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
113009:12-05 08:59:12.375 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 1     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:01 v2: 0:01
113037:12-05 08:59:12.376 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
146955:12-05 08:59:13.416 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 2     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:02 v2: 0:02
147049:12-05 08:59:13.419 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
183719:12-05 08:59:14.419 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 2     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:02 v2: 0:02
183795:12-05 08:59:14.421 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
196114:12-05 08:59:15.416 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 2     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:02 v2: 0:02
196134:12-05 08:59:15.417 23703 23703 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
```

---

LogCat Results from second run:

```
265847:12-05 09:02:17.836 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 0     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:00 v2: 0:00
265909:12-05 09:02:17.837 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
307358:12-05 09:02:19.284 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 0     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:00 v2: 0:00
307578:12-05 09:02:19.294 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
308183:12-05 09:02:19.367 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
313317:12-05 09:02:19.566 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 29    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:29 v2: 0:29
329426:12-05 09:02:20.143 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 0     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:00 v2: 0:00
329470:12-05 09:02:20.144 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
333076:12-05 09:02:20.273 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 2     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:02 v2: 0:02
333733:12-05 09:02:20.295 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
334562:12-05 09:02:20.321 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 28    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:28 v2: 0:28
363318:12-05 09:02:21.144 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 2     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:02 v2: 0:02
363380:12-05 09:02:21.145 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
366455:12-05 09:02:21.241 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 3     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:03 v2: 0:03
367007:12-05 09:02:21.252 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
367340:12-05 09:02:21.260 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 27    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:27 v2: 0:27
400725:12-05 09:02:22.137 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 4     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:04 v2: 0:04
400761:12-05 09:02:22.138 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
401053:12-05 09:02:22.149 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 26    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:26 v2: 0:26
441062:12-05 09:02:23.155 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
488508:12-05 09:02:24.775 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 30    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:30 v2: 0:30
488695:12-05 09:02:24.785 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 23    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:23 v2: 0:23
490056:12-05 09:02:25.198 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 23    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:23 v2: 0:23
509531:12-05 09:02:31.190 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 17    p1_i: 3 v3: 0:17 v2: 0:17
518767:12-05 09:02:34.145 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
519943:12-05 09:02:34.569 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 0     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:00 v2: 0:00
520099:12-05 09:02:34.603 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
536190:12-05 09:02:39.678 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 3     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:03 v2: 0:03
536210:12-05 09:02:39.679 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
537626:12-05 09:02:40.675 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 3     p1_i: 3 v3: 0:03 v2: 0:03
537646:12-05 09:02:40.676 24842 24842 W XXX p0_j: 490   p1_i: 3 v3: 8:10 v2: 8:10
```

Comment: This code has been obfuscated so it's going to be pretty hard to reverse engineer, especially just from this one snippet. It might be easier to describe the effect you want to achieve as there's plenty of ways of creating an animated countdown of text in Android.

Comment: Ian, I want to reduce the ad time to 0!

Comment: I posted a log of the results as an answer, bit Samuel Liew deleted them! Now sucessfully added to question.

Comment: Yes, Answers should be used to answer the question, not to add additional details about the question.